# Flows - Fast Lookup and Decision - Only Proceed If Record(s) Found

Tags: workflow, process-builder, administration, visual-workflow, automation

The following flow is meant to **delete GroupMembeship records for a given UserID.**

[image]

The **Fast Lookup** STEP 1 is as follows:

[image]

...while the **Decision** STEP 2 is as follows:

[image]

*I have a disconnect mentally on making the OUTCOME work on the Decision element.*

**I want "Found some" to happen IF any records were found during Fast Lookup.**  Else, "default" happens (which is linked to nothing).

When I test this with a user who does NOT HAVE a GroupMember record for a specific group, the DECISION element is going to "Found some".  Note the below Error Output (from email).  Somehow when I try using the sObject I THINK should be used, and select "is null", it still demands a Value on the right side of the screenshot.  When I use the name of the STEP 1 FAST LOOKUP, it at least allows use of "is null" with no value... but doesn't resolve correctly.

```
FAST LOOKUP: Find_GroupMember_records_for_the_UserID
Find all GroupMember records where:
UserOrGroupId Equals {!UserID} (00521000000WSYQAA4)
GroupId Equals {!GroupID} (00G21000000gVcp)
Assign those records to {!GroupMemberRecordsToDelete}.
Save these field values in the variable: Id

Result
Failed to find records.

DECISION: Find_any_records
>>>>>>>> Executed this outcome: Found_some <<<<<<<<
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!Find_GroupMember_records_for_the_UserID} (false) Does not equal null
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
```

My confusion is that the sObject I think I should be referencing at DECISION does not allow "is null" to be picked WITHOUT requiring a "value" be set, which makes no sense to me.   **HELP!**

*I cannot add a "Screen" for debugging as this is Automated and you can't edit it after saving as Automated, even if you SaveAs.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amm - you need to have your decision element that looks at your lookup to be: [Resource: Find_membership element equals True]

This will give you, if something is returned, do the next thing I want, and the default outcome is pointed to nothing.

[image]

Comment: ....and JUST like that, my Flow works perfectly.    True... as in, something was found (versus null).  Makes perfect sense (sigh)   Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

In the above solution you can omit the usage of loop and simply use the new feature from Winter 18, which allows you to get a count of the records directly. That count could act as your decision maker.

So to answer this question, all you simply need to do is like:

1. Perform a fast lookup with your required filters
   [image]
2. Assign the record count to a sObject collections variable. (in screenshot: nofCases)
3. Use a Assignment step, to assign the variable to a number variable. (Point to note: the assignment variable should be of type number only to make use of equals count operator. In the screenshot, this is called testCount)
   [image]
4. Voila! Now play around with the assigned variable :)